# Difficult nonlinear system based on max value

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let $ (a,b,c)$ be the real solution of the system of equations $ x^3 - xyz = 2$, $ y^3 - xyz = 6$, $ z^3 - xyz = 20$. The greatest possible value of $ a^3 + b^3 + c^3$ can be written in the form $ \frac{m}{n}$, where $ m$ and $ n$ are relatively prime positive integers. Find $ m + n$.

I got that:

$$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 28 + 3abc$$

I tried using a substitution,

$t = abc$ to get:

$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 28 + 3t$ but I cannot replace the LHS.

**Can somebody just help me with the substitution, thats all!?**

Comment: do you have solved this system

Comment: not yet @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.**

You have $$\left\{
    \begin{aligned}
x^3=2+t\\
y^3=6+t\\
z^3=20+t
    \end{aligned}
  \right.$$ Hence $$x^3 y^3 z^3 = t^3 = (2+t)(6+t)(20+t)$$

Comment: (+1) but what is the use of the product?

Comment: With this equation, you can find the product. And you have an equation linking the product to the sum to be maximized.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea of putting $t=xyz$ is quite correct. You then
have $x^3=t+6,y^3=t+6,z^3=t+20$, whence $t^3=(t+2)(t+6)(t+20)$. Expanding,
you see that $7t^2+43t+60=0$. The rest is easy and I leave it to you.
(by the way, the answer is $m+n=158$).

Comment: What is the use of the product though? (+1)